# Программа получает данные при помощи http-запроса, и печатает их по нажатию кнопки.

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

У меня несколько вопросов:

**1.** Почему  помещая кнопку в тег **script** я ее не вижу и не могу на нее нажать?

**2.** За что отвечает параметр **false** в методе open()?

---

В чем заключается ошибка моей программы? По нажатию кнопки мне ничего не выдает.

Вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  function getFile() {

    var xmlFileGet = XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlFileGet.open('GET','https://github.com/epamekids/epamekids.github.io/blob/master/README.md','false');
    xmlFileGet.send();

    alert(xmlFileGet);
  }
  </script>

  <button type = "button" onclick = "getFile">For printing text</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: 2)https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L16427 0) https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest

Answer (score 1):

> Почему помещая кнопку в тег script я ее не вижу и не могу на нее
>   нажать?

Потому что место внутри тега `script` предназначено для кода, а не для разметки.

> В чем заключается ошибка моей программы?

Ошибка #1. `<button type="button" onclick="getFile()">For printing text</button>`

Comment: а `new`, а `'false'` строкой

Comment: @qwabra Это ошибки 2 и 3 ).

Comment: :) а ретурнить 0 в onclick не обязательно?

Comment: @qwabra а  что значит false "строкой"?)

Comment: @qwabra а зачем ретурнить 0 в onclick?

Comment: @Михаил это не нужно

Comment: @Igor почему-то все равно  не печатает.